# C# MediaElement Video , how to add video from resources?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have the MediaElement and i want to play a video,
as i know the only way of doing so is to set this item Source

```
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(fileName);
```

but now i have the resources file which i wanna play but i cant do so because it doesnt have a path.
so to make a long story short, i'm looking for a way to play video in the madiaElement from the resources file(without writing its byte first).

Answer (score 6):

From first line in the **"Remarks"** section of the **MediaElement** docs: *"When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media file as a project resource. In your project file, you must instead set the media type to Content and set CopyToOutputDirectory to PreserveNewest or Always."*
So you can't play video from a resource. You can play a file attached to a project as content.
Some alternate ways described here..

- [media-element-wont-play-a-video](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c1c7b17f-872a-493f-8761-29c373204ed2/media-element-wont-play-a-video)
- [Accessing the resources in the published application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555952/accessing-the-resources-in-the-published-application)
- [Play embedded video resource as stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564044/play-embedded-video-resource-as-stream)
- [How to play a video from WinForms resources in a axWindowsMediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761331/how-to-play-a-video-from-winforms-resources-in-a-axwindowsmediaplayer)