# c# - how to completely embed a video to my windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, video, embed, video-player

for the past 2 days, i have been searching for a way to embed a video from my computer into my application completely so that i can send the application to other and they wouldnt need internet to play it.
the only results i got when i searched for it was to embed youtube videos, windows media player, vlc...etc into your application.
 i closest i cam to finding the answer is when you embed windows media player add it in your form then use this code
             axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\user\myvideos\videotoplay";
but when i took the application to a friends computuer, he didnt have any location like c:\use\myvideos or even the 'videotoplay'which meant the video was not embeded completely

my last hope is to come here hoping that it is possible
thnx in advance for your help

Comment: so if you embedded "The lord of the rings" in your app your .exe should weight around 2 GB... is that ok for you?, is that what you are looking for??

Comment: yes, i'm ok with that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MediaElement Video , how to add video from resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474750/c-sharp-mediaelement-video-how-to-add-video-from-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [including](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx) your video file in your project and then getting the file path to it with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` so it would look like that:

`axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"videotoplay");`

Comment: yeah, t still didnt play offline